# Pytorch: how is FSDP optimizer state sharding implemented?

Tags: python, pytorch

I've been to trying understand how pytorch implements FSDP (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/fsdp.html). So far I understand param and gradient sharding and forward and backward passes, but I still fail to see how FSDP can interact with optimizer state sharding. The reasons I'm confused:

- FSDP doesn't require "wrapping" the optimizer in any way: you just use your normal optimizer.
- Optimizer implementations put optimizer state into `self.state` and IIUC can put arbitrary tensors there?
- Reading through the FSDP source I see some methods that shard/unshard optimizer state, but they all take the optimizer as an argument, and their uses in pytorch are for serialization/deserialization, not training.

So, I don't understand how in a standard training loop:

```
sharded_module = FSDP(my_module)
optim = torch.optim.Adam(sharded_module.parameters(), lr=0.0001)
x = sharded_module(x, y=3, z=torch.Tensor([1]))
loss = x.sum()
loss.backward()
optim.step()
```

the optimizer state gets sharded between nodes. Or even how the FSDP code can reference the optimizer state, given that we don't pass `optim` to the FSDP wrapper?

Answer (score 1):

FSDP shards paramters, gradients, and optimizer states if you use the FULL_SHARD algorithm (default in FSDP). For sharded optimizer states, this happens eagerly, i.e. when optimizer's .step() is called, it is called on sharded gradients. torch optimizers initialize optim state lazily, so the state is constructed based on the gradient shapes in the first .step() call. since the gradients are sharded, the optimizer states end up sharded by extension as well.